# How to loot a wrecked space ship with only small inventory space availabe?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I'm in front of wrecked space ship (it was sending an emergency signal).
It is full of broken technology.

Two questions:
**a)** How can identify the hidden technology and its value behind the "broken" icon?

**b)** My inventory is nearly full. What is the best way to loot such a wrecked ship?
 Can I mark it as "my property"? Can I transfer it to a save place? How do you handle such treasures?

Comment: You should split your questions into separate posts. Otherwise, it will be closed for being too broad

Comment: Plus, question that can be answered by looking at your screen are generally not well received. Your questions are both based on false premises. You do not loot such a ship, if you want to use it you repair it. And you claim it like every other vessel, just look at the lower right of your screen.

Answer (score 2):

**A:** There is no technology hidden behind the broken icon. When you repair the technology it merely frees the slot for use to store items or to install technologies.

**B:** If you don't want the ship, you can deconstruct the technologies in the ship that the game lets you deconstruct to get some resources. You can also claim the ship by interacting with it and if you have a capital ship it will be stored there once you leave the planet. Your capital ship can store up to 6 starships at a time.